# How useful is a behavior like this?

Tags: discussion

Take in consideration [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803243/under-what-conditions-is-a-facebook-graph-data-populated-with-permissions-stat).

This question asks about a behavior regarding Facebook (a Facebook application). Since I was working in a project requiring a library, and got a weird behavior (the permissions appear to be "status" and "permissions" instead of the already asked and approved). For such problem I detailed (and linked) the packages being used. In such question, I detail the component (unambiguously defined) with such behavior.

The question got even a vote to close: "Unclear what you're asking".

My question is: What is "unclear" about asking: "Why are such permissions prepopulated instead of the granted ones?"?

Comment: Word of advice; edit to make this less "ranty". People generally don't link being yelled at. I wouldn't have VTC btw. It seems very borderline to me.

Comment: Someone is saying that he feels that the question is unclear and he doesn't feel that it is answerable.  How is that *not* useful?  If other people have no problem understanding the question then they can help clarify the question, as well as potentially answering it or participating in other ways.  If other people can't understand it, then the question will end up closed.  This is why it takes 5 votes to close, not 1.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET u're right. I edited the question.

Comment: I edited out the rant at the beginning since it doesn't seem to contribute to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we look at "unclear what you're asking" close reason it says:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard
>   to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to
>   Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help
>   clarifying this question.

You have a very *specific* problem, but your question lacks additional details.

What are these "certain unknown conditions" (that nobody is able to reproduce but you?) What does "facebook-wise" mean and what kind of answer do you expect to that question? Your comment "I leave, however, the django tag - perhaps someone had the same problem" expresses uncertainty with what exactly the issue is or where it lies.

The burden lies on the question asker to clarify the problem and not on others to read your mind. Alternatively, it could be because your question relies on two very specific technologies that the barrier of knowledge is higher. Your question would only make sense to a small group of people familiar with the technology.

Comment: I can tell where is it occurring (a django middleware). I cannot tell why is it ocurring. Perhaps those permissions (status, permission) are something related to a misconfiguration (or bug) of an application trying to connect to Facebook, and that's what I was asking - since I've never seen such permissions.

Comment: The "why is it ocurring", or at least a list of possibilities, is that what I am asking there. I expected a "facebook-wise" point of view, since, perhaps, I'd making a mistake which is not related to the used tecnhnology, but to facebook platform (e.g. not passing a secret, using an old oauth token, ...).

Answer (score 4):

I read your question and at first glance it was very difficult to read.  The first time through it felt like it was just a lot of information just smattered all over the page.  There didn't feel like there was much continuity to it, like it wasn't leading up to something.  Even after a another read thru I'm still not sure what it is about. (Note: I know nothing about Django, so I won't downvote / vote to close.  It could be salvageable by someone more knowledgeable than me.)

You also start by talking about a framework and then at the end say it isn't a framework thing.  Which is it?  If it is a framework thing, you need to help us help you by narrowing down when it happens and what it is doing that is wrong.  You say it happens under "certain unknown conditions".  No one will be able to tell you why something is happening if they don't even get a clue about when it happens.

If it isn't a framework thing and is a question about Facebook and how something will affect Facebook, the Facebook docs are probably a better place to look for answers.  If you need to know how this behavior will affect what you are doing, we need to know more about what you are doing.

Long story short, your question feels like it is all over the place and without reading it multiple times it's hard to get even a tenuous grasp on what you want.